# compareTo with Comparable<Object>

Tags: java

So using somebody else's code, I have two comparable objects:

```
Comparable<Object> result1 =
Comparable<Object> result2 =
```

To sort them, the code calls

```
result1.compareTo(result2);
```

Most of the time it works, except when it doesn't. And I am stuck with:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Double to java.lang.Long
```

Obviously if I knew what the types were advance it would be possible to cast them, but I don't.

Also randomly comparing with String does not give the expect result, so this is not good either:

```
retval = result1.toString().compareTo(result2.toString());
```

I don't have guava, or any third party library available, so the question is, how can I reliably compare result1 and result2 ?

**Update1**

result1 and result2 objects will always be comparable. (either both of types String, or Date, or here Long/Double)
The problem here is that I get Long and Double which, to me, are comparable, but through a class cast exception with java.

**Update2**
Code is from the CSVJDBC driver.
Failing line is:

https://sourceforge.net/p/csvjdbc/code/ci/master/tree/src/main/java/org/relique/jdbc/csv/CsvResultSet.java#l179

Comment: Why do you think you can compare incompatible objects?  How can it be meaningful to do so?  This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info), and unless you explain the real goal nobody here can help you.

Comment: @jim updated the question, with details.

Comment: You'll notice that `Double` implements `Comparable<Double>` and `Long`, `Comparable<Long>`.

Comment: @NicolasModrzyk is it feasible to post whole code at least the few lines?

Comment: @Phil, yes I have noticed... thanks !

Comment: @vishrant added the failing line.

Comment: More to the point, `Long#compareTo(Object o)` was not written to support comparing to Double, and you can’t change it.  But you can test if the objects are `instanceof Number` and use `Number#doubleValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on @AJNeufeld's comment, now using this:

```
if(result1 instanceof Number && result2 instanceof Number) {
   retval = Double.compare(
              ((Number)result1).doubleValue(),
              ((Number)result2).doubleValue());
}  else {
   retval = result1.compareTo(result2);
}
```

but if someone has a better solution ...

Comment: This still fails on the else branch when the types are not compatible.  You would need to implement meaningful comparisons between all possible types.  It feels like the design is flawed if you need to do this, but I don’t have the time to read all your code and fix the design.  You seem to be writing a library, but something’s seriously wrong with the approach.

Comment: Your right to keep searching for a better solution.  I did not post the above as an answer for a reason.  `Long` has 63 bits of precision, where `Double` only has 52, so comparing two non-equal very large `Long` values can result in equality when converted to `double` values.  Also, `NaN` values are not comparable, being neither less than, equal to, nor greater than any value, including another `NaN`, so they should be special cased as well.  But the above solution will work, if your values are restricted to a “behaving” range.

Comment: @jim you are correct regarding the else branch. I am not writing that library, but I need to use it (this CSVJDBC driver) That driver ... has a bug at this specific *compare* code, where I get the ClassCastException, and I would like to fix it. Just like you, I haven't read all the code, nor all the design. This being a JDBC driver, I am supposing the to-be-compared objects would be of comparable types and so the problem only arise when comparing numbers. (Float, Double, Long etc ...)